# Multiple user seeing the same items in shopping cart

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

I have  created a shopping cart using session to store the item being added to cart.Upon deployment i found out that the shopping cart is not unique to the user that is other user are getting items added to the cart by other user.

I tried to use the login username in the session name to make the session unique to that user but it is not working.

```
 public class ListOfDataset
 {

        static ListOfDataset()
        {

            string username = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name;

            // If the cart is not in the session, create one and put it there
            // Otherwise, get it from the session
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session[string.Format("ASPNETShoppingCart-{0}", username)] == null)
            {
                Instance = new ListOfDataset();
                Instance.Items = new List<DataSet>();
                HttpContext.Current.Session[string.Format("ASPNETShoppingCart-{0}", username)] = Instance;
            }
            else
            {
                Instance = (ListOfDataset)HttpContext.Current.Session[string.Format("ASPNETShoppingCart-{0}", username)];
            }
        }
}
```

Updated code,error in  else statement-object reference not set and function ChekIfdatasetexist always return false:

```
 public class ListOfDataset
    {



        public static ListOfDataset Instance
        {
            get
            {

                ListOfDataset cart = null;

                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"] == null)
                {
                    cart = new ListOfDataset();

                    cart.Items = new List<DataSet>();

                    HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"] = cart.Items;

                }
                else
                {

                    cart.Items =(List<DataSet> )HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"];
                }

                return cart;
            }
        }

        public List<DataSet> Items { get; private set; }

        public void AddItem(DataSet itemdataset)
        {

            Items.Add(itemdataset);

            HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"] = Items;
        }

        public bool CheckIfDataSetExist(string servicename)
        {
            DataSet DataSetexist = null;

            if (Items != null)
            {
                DataSetexist = Items.Where(i => i.DataSetName == servicename).FirstOrDefault();
            }


            if (DataSetexist != null) return true;

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check the value `HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID` - it should be different per user, otherwise the session management is messed up or you have somehow done a `session hijacking`.

Comment: Not sure what a `ListOfDataset` is, but it looks like you are creating one `static` application-wide instance of something and always re-using it.

Comment: How did you noticed that the sessions are same for multiple users? Did you opened your page in multiple tabs or opened it in another browser at the same time?

Comment: @CodeTherapist Upon deployment on IIS,how do i check that ID?

Comment: @keshav simply log this information - but it seems that you re-use always the same instance of  `ListOfDataset` with a static reference to `HttpContext.Current.Session` that would be always the same.

Comment: @FarhadMehrad i used two different PC with different users. I did notice that if i log with the same user on another PC the cart is still here!!!

Comment: So David is right. Change the ListOfDataset to instance member and apply some synchronization stuff.

Comment: @FarhadMehrad am getting error: object not set to an instance at this line:

  if (HttpContext.Current.Session["ASPNETShoppingCart"] == null)

Comment: Go and check your code again to see if you've accidentally disabled SessionStateModule or not? and make sure you're filling your session before accessing it. Check that HttpContext.Current and HttpContex.Current.Session are not null.

Comment: @FarhadMehrad Please see updated question,  I keep getting error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.DataSet]' to type 'Crawling.BLL.ListOfDataset'.' at the else part

Comment: You can not cast different types of objects implicitly or explicitly when there is no hierarchy between them. Casting does not help that way. You have to map one to another using a mapper like AutoMapper or do that manually.

Comment: @FarhadMehrad code updated no casting problem anymore,can you check for the new error please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here.

1. As someone said in comments you have made the Instance member static, which means it will remain the same application wide and shared among users.
2. Session is not the best place to store per user data cause it will blow up your server memory and wont scale. Better use a database to store the data.

Comment: can you show the code change for the static part please

Comment: I keep getting error : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Data.DataSet]' to type 'Crawling.BLL.ListOfDataset'.'    at the else part @shbht_twr